# Problem to find data from mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, ejs

When I trying to get data from mongo b database I am getting whole object like
_id, title (all property of that object) . But I need only the title. How I can fix this?

**models and mongo schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const IntroSchema = new Schema ({
 title: {
     type: String,
     required: true
 }
 });

let Intro = module.exports = mongoose.model("Intro", IntroSchema);
```

**This is request to get data**

**app.js**

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
Intro.find({}, (err, title) => {
if (err) {
  res.send("Something went wrong: " + err);
} else {
  res.render('index', {
    title
  })
}
});
});
```

rendering though ejs view engine.

**index.ejs**

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
```

[See full project on github](https://github.com/MdSamsuzzohaShayon/dynamic-business-website)

Answer (score 1):

You might have confused yourself naming the response title.

Try:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Intro.find({}, (err, items) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send("Something went wrong: " + err);
    } else {
      res.render('index', {
        title: items[0].title
      })
    }
  });
});
```